# Getting a segmentation fault while reading from file

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, allocation

I am dealing with structures and char pointers (strings). I want to make an an array of structures and those structures have a `char*`, and two `int`s.

I am getting a segmentation fault when attempting to `fscanf` into the `array` and `struct`s.

Here is the relevant part of my code.

**Struct Def**

```
typedef struct {
    char* title;
    int gross;
    int year;
} Movie;
```

**Function I am heaving issues with**

```
Movie* createArray(char *filename, int size)
{

    FILE *f;
    f = fopen(filename, "r");
    Movie* arr = (Movie*) malloc(sizeof(Movie) * size);
    if(!arr){printf("\nAllocation Failed\n"); exit(1);}
    for (int i =0; i<size; i++){
        fscanf(f, "%s %d %d", (arr+ i)->title, &arr[i].gross, &arr[i].year);
    }
    fclose(f);
    return arr;

}
```

To add on to that in case it is needed here is how I call the function

```
        Movie* arr = createArray(file1, records);
```

Comment: `title` is a pointer, you need to reserve memory for it or simply declare it as a char array:

Comment: You may want to pick either pointer notation or index notion, both looks awkward in `(arr+ i)->title, &arr[i].gross, &arr[i].year` -- nothing wrong with it, it just reads a bit odd.

Comment: @CRedmond, I noticed that you have asked some questions already on the site and you are yet to [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) despite having a couple of good ones, accepting answers is an important feature of the site, not only it rewards the poster but also signals the answer that solved the problem proposed by the question for future viewers.

Answer (score 2):

`title` is an uninitialized pointer, you will also need to reserve memory for it, or simply declare `title` as a `char array` with desired size if that's an option.

There some other issues I felt like addressing in your function, some of them you might be aware of, code below with comments.

```
Movie* createArray(char *filename, int size)
{
    FILE *f;

    if(!(f = fopen(filename, "r"))){ //also check for file opening
        perror("File not found");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //or return NULL and handle it on the caller
     }  

    //don't cast malloc, #include <stdlib.h>, using the dereferenced pointer in sizeof
    //is a trick commonly  used to avoid future problems if the type needs to be changed
    Movie* arr = malloc(sizeof(*arr) * size);    

    if(!arr) {
        perror("Allocation Failed"); //perror is used to output the error signature
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (int i =0; i<size; i++) {
        if(!((arr + i)->title = malloc(100))){ // 99 chars plus null terminator, 
            perror("Allocation failed");       // needs to be freed before the array
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);   //using EXIT_FAILURE macro is more portable 
        }

        //always check fscanf return, and use %99s specifier 
        //for 100 chars container to avoid overflow
        if(fscanf(f, "%99s %d %d", (arr+ i)->title, &arr[i].gross, &arr[i].year) != 3){ 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); //or return NULL and handle it on the caller
        }
    }
    fclose(f);
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Good answer, except I would also fix the spacing in the `arr`-nullcheck line.
Also, do not forget to free the `title` for each element of the array before you free the array itself.